# How to isolate processes? Searching for single-node alternative to slurm

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, jobs, hpc, slurm

I'd like to provide a process with limited number of cores and limited memory.
With slurm, I'd solve this with a command like the following:

```sh
srun --pty -c32 --mem=178G bash
```

How would I do this without slurm on a normal desktop computer?

Comment: Look at ulimits and probably better, running the process within a container running with resource limits

Comment: I'm searching for a direct replacement to this slurm command.
As far as I understand, ulimits and containers are not helpful to this end. Ulimits only force e.g. upper process count. Containers run their own OS but I want to run on the host environment.

Comment: A proper replacement would probably need to be based on cgroups

Comment: Container don't run their own OS but rather their own runtime as a separate isolated process ID on the same OS. This is where they differ from virtual machines. Also, containers' original design built on cgroups.

Comment: Thanks, got your point. Still, I want to use the host runtime without changing users, etc.